# How to use ToString to convert with Precision?

Tags: vb.net

This is the question

> Use the ToString method with a format string to convert the double
>   variable , pi to the string variable , s, in fixed point format and 4
>   digits of precision.

What I have so far is `s = pi.ToString()` I'm just not sure what to put inside the parenthesis

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: `s = pi.ToString("F4")`
Thank you